# duda contruccion formulario

Tags: laravel-5

Buen dia

Tengo un formulario que realice dentro una celda de una tabla , lo que tengo alli funciona bien.

https://paste.laravel.io/c3f424ec-707d-4a66-b0c4-db2d3920c3af

El problema es que yo queria dejar el boton en una celda por aparte, pero no es posible, ya que esto divide mi formulario, por lo tanto no funciona, hay alguna manera de lograr esto?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner tu botón fuera del formulario en la celda que desees. Y ocultar el botón de tu formulario.

Desde el de fuera puedes llamar a la función click del botón del formulario con javascript. Suponiendo que al botón de dentro le pones `id = "formButton"` te quedaría algo así el botón exterior.

```
<input type="button" id="externalButton" onclick="document.getElementById('formButton').click()" />
```

Saludos,